# Is it possible to communicate between different rest clients using a common API of another application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Let's say we have three applications called A,B and C B is an email sending application,and it has a method to send an email like sendEmail(String email) now I need to call that function from A through the rest API of C(Here A and B are rest consumers who can use C as a Common API).Can I do something like that?. I mean you can see there is no any direct communication between A and B so I am simply asking can I use rest API as the one who links them ?I know there is rest template and other rest consuming technologies available to do the consuming tasks,but in all those scenarios there is only two way data exchanging ,which is most probably with a client and a server(Rest service provider and consumer) and there won't be something like server is calling the client,because in every time client is calling the server methods(Get,post,put,delete) .but here you can see we need some kind of a method to call the sendEmail(String email) function of email sending application through the server so basically to do so server(Rest services provider) needs to have an object of that email sending application.How is this possible?

**If you doesn't understand the scenario please tell me at-least is it possible to invoke a method of a rest consumer from rest API(rest server)? , because normally we call the methods of rest API from rest consumer** [I am using spring boot]

Answer (score 0):

In any case you need to invoke REST method to invoke your sendEmail method because you client is also a REST client and it can communicate with REST method

Answer (score 0):

If you need A to call B directly, you need to have B expose the email sending capability as a REST Endpoint if it doesn't already exist.

Then you can use the Spring Rest Template capability to call application B from A. Make changes to A to use Spring Rest Template and then make the relevant call.

Comment: Yeah In the assignment given they are saying to have only one rest API ,that's the problem So they are saying to use that API and communicate between all other clients.